# how to take value from xml file in .net c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

i have an xml file i want to get inner text by using linq.Xml is as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<testObject class="LN" version="16A" distName="CEL-1" id="456" xmlns="kaml20.xsd">
  <p name="rcc">424</p>
  <p name="kcc">02</p>
  <p name="testname">testobject</p>
</testObject>
```

and i did the following code with no result

```
private static string GetvalueNokia(XElement pin, string val)
{
    string fname="";
    try
    {
        //string location = pin.Descendants("cellName").Single().Value;

        //return pin
        //.Descendants("p")
        //.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value.ToUpper() == val.ToUpper())).Value;
        ////.Attribute("value").Value;

        var data = from atts in pin.Elements("name")
                   select new
                   {
                       cell= (string)atts.Element("name")
                   };
     }
}
```

**EDIT**
my pin is as shwon below

```
<testObject class="LN" version="16A" distName="CEL-1" id="456" xmlns="kaml20.xsd">
  <p name="cellName">testname</p>
  <p name="rcc">424</p>
  <p name="kcc">02</p>
</testObject>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get the inner text of the xml node which has a particular value in the `name` attribute, if that's correct, you can try the following code:

```
var data = (from node in pin.Descendants("name")
            where node.Attribute("name") !=null &&  node.Attribute("name").Value == value
           select new
           {
              AttributeValue = node.Attribute("name").Value,
              InnerText = node.Value
           });
```

We need to first filter the nodes which have attribute `name` and in combination with that it contains the value which is provided as input.

and if you want to do case-insenstive comparison of the input parameter in xml nodes attribute, then you can use `String.Compare` like:

```
String.Equals(node.Attribute("name").Value, value,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

and if `pin` is the element from which you are trying to get the `name` attribute value, then just call the `Attribute` method on it with the attribute name as input and access the `Value` property like:

```
private static string GetvalueNokia(XElement pin, string val)
{ 
  return pin.Attribute("name")?.Value;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks i wil try and let u know the results